# How to clear the Jump List for Remote Desktop?

Tags: windows-7, jumplist

How can I clear all automatically added Jump List items for Remote Desktop?

Answer (score 3):

Jump Lists are stored as files in `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations`. The file for Remote Desktop is called `1bc392b8e104a00e.automaticDestinations-ms`.

Delete it to clear the Jump List.

Restrict its file permissions to block Explorer from changing it. Make it a zero-byte file to forever block the Jump List for this program.