# Context Menu of Pinned File in Taskbar - Where is this File?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, context-menu

[image: Here you can see the Conext Menu]

Question states it already.
I want to know where the Pinned File is located on the hard drive.
I can open it with a left-click.
I can not search for it because of #!$%§ windows see Image number 2.

[image: No Results found for *.rdp - because you know ... windows ...]

A right-click with all the known modifiers (alt-shift-ctrl in every combination) just gives a single item context menu of "Open". Is there something i am missing? Where is the real context-menu?

Thanks for your help in advance.

edit:
Yes i see the related questions. But none are asking for the files - they ask for the pinned applications. As you can see in the first Image i want to get the location of the first pinned file.

Comment: This SO Windows 7 link may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945320/where-is-win7s-jump-list-system-data-stored ... it seems the data is stored in files but I've no idea how to open the file (they have some binary content)... a Hex program showed some content but not sure how I'd go about adding,editing or deleting without looking to VisualStudio and writing using programming for Windows

Comment: You can analyze the jump lists of Remote Desktop by [analyzing 1bc392b8e104a00e.automaticDestinations-ms](https://superuser.com/a/786287/167187)

Comment: You can use [JumpLister by Mark Woan](http://www.woanware.co.uk/forensics/jumplister.html) or [MiTeC's Structured Storage Viewer](http://www.mitec.cz/ssv.html) to see if you can find what you're looking for. Looking through the strings in SSViewer's `As Text` view may help too.

Comment: could it be the file does no longer exist? Try to add another one (which *is* existing for sure), and see if the right-click gives more options.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These files are located in the jump-lists folders, which are divided into
two kinds.

- The ones the operating system creates and maintains store information about data file usage and are to be found in files named like this :
  `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\[AppID].automaticDestinations-ms`.
- The ones maintained by specific applications responsible for that specific destination file are to be found in files named like this :
  `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations\[AppID].customDestinations-ms`.

The names for the files are not very informative, so one has to look
into their content in order to find more information.
Some AppIDs can be found in the [List of Jump List IDs](http://forensicswiki.org/wiki/List_of_Jump_List_IDs).

Much information about jump-lists is found in the description of
[Windows Jump List Parser (jmp)](https://www.tzworks.net/prototype_page.php?proto_id=20) - a free utility that can be used to parse
these jump-list files.

Below is a screenshot of the types of information that can be extracted
by using *jmp* :

[image]

I have not tried this product, but from the above screenshot
it seems that to see the target file one must use the paid version of *jmp*
($210).

In that case, use the information from the article
[ForensicsWiki : Jump Lists](http://forensicswiki.org/wiki/Jump_Lists) :

[image: image2]

Comment: FYI the links in your answer no longer work. The one for jump list IDs has moved to https://forensicswiki.xyz/wiki/index.php?title=List_of_Jump_List_IDs and jump list parser seems to now be located at https://tzworks.com/prototype_page.php?proto_id=20

Answer (score 3):

The technical term is a jump list.

[NirSoft JumpListView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/jump_lists_view.html) should help you in listing the details of the jump list and providing the paths.

[Search Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) should also find them, as long as they are located on a local hard disk. This tool will not analyze the jump list, but read the MFT directly.

Comment: Another decent parser I just found (JumpList Explorer) is available from Eric Zimmerman: https://ericzimmerman.github.io/

Answer (score -3):

You can find pinned apps in:

%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar

and for the start menu apps go to:

%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\StartMenu

Check this original Source : [Where is the list of pinned start menu and taskbar items stored in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/171096/where-is-the-list-of-pinned-start-menu-and-taskbar-items-stored-in-windows-7)

Comment: I'm sorry to say but: this is just the list of pinned apps. This is NOT the list of pinned files - as i have stated in my question.